# Node/Express.js mocha setup not working

Tags: node.js, express, mocha.js

Here is my test file:

```
var request = require('superagent'),
    expect = require('expect'),
    sinon = require('sinon'),
    app = require("../../../../app");

request = request(app);

describe("HealthCheck", function () {

    describe("/health_check", function () {
        it("should return a 200 status", function (done) {
            request
            .get("http://localhost:3000/health_check")
            .end(function(err, res) {
                expect(res).to.exist;
                expect(res.status).to.equal(200);
                expect(res.body).to.contain('OK');

                return done();
            });
        });
    });
})
```

The error I keep running into is

```
  1) HealthCheck /health_check should return a 200 status:
     TypeError: Cannot call method 'end' of undefined
```

Can't figure out what I am doing wrong

Here is my app.js:

```
require('coffee-script/register');

var express = require('express'),
  config = require('./config/config'),
  fs = require('fs');

var app = express();

require('./config/express')(app, config);

app.listen(config.port);

exports.app = app;
```

Comment: looks like there may be something up with your app... could you post what is in app?

Comment: hmm.. exports.app = app - i think that maybe the issue - in your test, where you've got request = request(app); try changing it to request = request(app.app);

Comment: @dennismonsewicz Please do not update your question by adding an answer into it. You should remove the answer from your question and submit it as a separate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're exporting app as `app`
Therefore, when you `require` the module, you'll need to `require` the name of the function you're exporting - in this case 'app'

So, you can either change your test

```
var request = require('superagent'),
    expect = require('expect'),
    sinon = require('sinon'),
    app = require("../../../../app");

request = request(app.app);
```

Or change your `app.js` to exports a single function:

Change

```
exports.app = app;
```

to

```
module.exports = app;
```

There's a good article on this here: http://openmymind.net/2012/2/3/Node-Require-and-Exports/

Comment: haha, I must have been posting my working code as you were answering this question! Thanks! I'll accept yours as the answer